# In React, global state goes out of sync when route parameters are manually changed in url

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, use-context

We have a variable in our React application that is both:

1. Defined as global state in `App.js`, passed globally with its setter method to other components via the `GlobalContext.Provider`, and
2. Used separately as a route parameter for many of the app's routes.

Below is a short code snippet of the relevant section of our `App.js` file then:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import GlobalContext from './context/GlobalContext';
import OtherComponents...

function App() {
    const [competition, setCompetition] = useState({ value: 15, label: 'Season 1' });

    return (
        <GlobalContext.Provider value={{ // Pass Global State Through To Entire App
            competition, setCompetition
        }}>
            <Navbar />
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/' render={(props) => <HomePage {...props} />} />
                <Route exact path='/stats' component={StatsPage} />
                <Route exact path='/about' component={AboutUs} />
                <Route exact path='/persons/:competitionId/ component={PersonsComponent} />
                <Route exact path='/teams/:competitionId component={TeamsComponent} />
            </Switch>
        </GlobalContext.Provider>
    );
}

export default App;
```

The `competition` global state has keys `value` and `label`, and the `competitionId` in the url parameter is then the same valu as the `competition.value` value.

The global state value for `competition` is meant to be changed in the `<Navbar>` component using a `select` widget. When this widget is toggled, the global state is updated, and the `useHistory` hook is used to push to app to the new route, using the updated `competition.value` to set the `competitionId` url parameter.

The value for `competition` is **needed** in many components in our application, including those components where there are no url parameters (e.g. in the `<HomePage>` component). For this reason, we feel that it is needed as a global variable, passed down to all other components. This is also very convenient for us as the variable is easily accessibly anywhere with the `useContext` hook.

However, the value also seems **needed** in our url parameters. These components fetch different data based on the `competitionId` passed, and them being in the url parameters is a big part of the routing of the app.

**Our Problem** is then that users can manually change the website's url, which can change the url parameters **without also changing the global state of the variable**. By changing the url manually, rather than with the `select` widget, the global state and url parameters then go out of sync...

**Edit:** Here is the `select` component that we use to toggle the `competition` value (sorry the post is getting long). This select is up in our Navbar, and is globally acessable as it's outside our `<Switch>`:

```
function CompetitionSelect({ currentPath }) {
    // Grab History In Order To Push To Selected Pages
    let history = useHistory();
    let { competition, setCompetition } = useContext(GlobalContext);

    // Fetch Data on All Competitions (dropdown options)
    const competitionInfosConfig = {};
    const [competitionInfos, isLoading1, isError1] = useInternalApi('competitionInfo', [], competitionInfosConfig);

    // Messy digging of competitionId out of current path.
    let competitionIds = competitionInfos.map(row => row.competitionId);
    let pathCompetitionId = null;
    competitionIds.forEach(id => {
        if (currentPath.includes(`/${id}/`)) {
            pathCompetitionId = id;
        }
    });

    // Messy Handling State/Params Out Of Sync
    if (pathCompetitionId === null) {
        console.log('Not a page where testing is needed');
    }
    else if (competition.value !== pathCompetitionId) {
        console.log('WERE OUT OF SYNC...');
        let correctGlobalState = { value: pathCompetitionId, label: 'Label Set' };
        setCompetition(correctGlobalState);
    } else {
        console.log('IN SYNC: ', competition.value, ' == ', pathCompetitionId);
    }

    // Handle updating state + pushing to new route
    const handleSelect = (event) => {
        let oldPath = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(history.location.pathname));
        let newPath = '';
        competitionIds.forEach(id => {
            if (oldPath.includes(`/${id}/`)) {
                newPath = oldPath.replace(`/${id}/`, `/${event.value}/`)
            }
        });

        if (newPath !== '') {
            setCompetition(event);
            history.push(newPath);
        }
    };

    // Create The Select
    const competitionSelect =
        (<Select
            styles={appSelectStyles}
            value={competition}
            options={competitionInfos}
            onChange={handleSelect}
            placeholder={'Select Competition'}
        />);

    return (
        {competitionSelect}
    );
}

export default CompetitionSelect;
```

This component technically does resolve the out-of-sync issue in the `if, if else, else` clause, however whenever `setCompetition(correctGlobalState)` is called, React throws the following warning message:

`Warning: Cannot update a component (`App`) while rendering a different component (`CompetitionSelect`). To locate the bad setState() call inside` CompetitionSelect`, follow the stack trace as described...`

Comment: Shouldn't you treat url as the state?

Comment: Maybe? I'm not sure what is best, although it does seem like the url params and the global state are duplicative...

Comment: I would try to avoid duplication of state and make data only flow in one direction. When the user changes the dropdown value, update the url, and re-render the component.

Comment: One positive about the global state is that is globally accessible from all components, whereas I can only get route parameters from the top-level `route` components (not the nested components).

When `useParams()` is run from within a nested component not defined in the `App.js` `<Switch/>`, it returns an empty object...

Comment: It will be much easier having one source of truth (the url param) and passing it down wherever you need it. I don't understand where you would need it without having it available on the `useParams` response. Would you show an example where you can't use `useParams`?

Comment: See the 4th edit. Pretty much, we need access to this global `competition` value even on pages without the `competition` url parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a good way to deal with this is

- attempt to get competition data out of the URL
- use that as the initial value for the state if available, or a default if not
- use a `useEffect` to update the state with this competition data from the URL if it's available, on location change

For example

```
function App() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const params = useParams();

  // implement getCompetitionFromParams as appropriate
  // returns undefined if no competition data in URL params
  const competitionFromParams = getCompetitionFromParams(location, params)

  const [competition, setCompetition] = 
    // init state on first load, 
    // with default if competitionFromParams not available
    useState(competitionFromParams || { value: 15, label: 'Season 1' });


  // update state on location change,
  // if competitionFromParams available
  useEffect(() => {
    if (competitionFromParams !== undefined) {
      setCompetition(competitionFromParams); 
    }
  }, [location]); // runs useEffect only on location change

  ...
```

With that, you get what you want - `competition` in global state, the ability to set it manually with a select, but also have it auto-synced when it appears in the relevant URL parameters.

Comment: This looks great. However, by having this in the `App.js` file, wouldn't this introduce an additional re-render of the page every single time the location changes (assuming `competitionFromParams !== undefined` and we run `setCompetition`)

Comment: Yes, that's true. This isn't optimised, it's more just to demonstrate the general mechanism, but for example you could optimise this more by adding the relevant competition data values from `params` to the `useEffect` dependencies, so state is updated not only when location changes but when the actual competition data changes too. Whether or not that kind of optimisation is necessary I guess depends on your app & performance requirements.